# why is one dependency not packaged with the JAR in Maven project

Tags: maven

EDIT: see the edit below. This question still needs attention because changing the pom as suggested did not change the behavior even after a clean.

I have a Java Maven project with a plugin to produce a standalone JAR which has thus far worked perfectly. In the pom.xml,

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>ptcs.App</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I recently wanted to use the Fraction class from org.apache.commons.math3, so I did the following. In my code,

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.fraction.Fraction;
```

Adding a dependency to pom.xml,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

EDIT: originally test was in the pom, but I removed it. There was no change in the behavior. I have also cleaned the project.

I'm working in VS Code, which puts a little "run" button above `public static void main`. That run button works, but trying to run the JAR reports there is no class definition for Fraction. Also running `mvn java:exec ...` reports the same problem.

What am I doing wrong, and why did it work perfectly before adding this dependency?

The error I get when running the JAR is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache 
/commons/math3/fraction/Fraction
    at ptcs.App.main(App.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:        
org.apache.commons.math3.fraction.Fraction
    at
```

java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
      at
    java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLo

```
aders.java:178)

    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)

    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 3):

Thats because the dependency is marked for scope `test` only and that means the dependency is only needed in the test phase.

The build process to make the jar file exclude these files from the packaged jar file and also exclude that file when starting the application with `mvn java:exec ...`.

To fix it simple remove `<scope>test</scope>`

Comment: Thanks but that didn't change anything. I edited my question to include the output when I try to run `java -jar target/<jar name>`

Comment: Did you build a new jar file before executing the jar file? Try `mvn clean package` to build new jar file and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Is the package in the jar contained? Moreover, did you use the maven-dependency-plugin?

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: I didn't have the `maven-dependency-plugin` in the `pom.xml`, but I just added it and it didn't change the behavior. I don't know what it means for the "package in the jar to be contained"?

Comment: You can open the jar because it is a zip and thereby look into the jar and the contained classes etc.With this, it is possible to verify if all is packaged.